# Fetching incomplete object with Hibernate Mapping as native query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Consider an Entity which has four fields (yes it is not a valid Java code, just for demonstration):

```
@Entity
Sale {
    id, date, name, kind
}
```

I can select his entity with entity manager easily as:

```
em.find(Sale.class, id)
```

However if I wanted to make a simpler query and fill this object, I could do it via native query as Simple object:

```
em.createNativeQuery("SELECT s.id, s.date FROM sale s", Sale.class)
```

The problem is that as there are missing fields, I am getting errors of missing columns: `SQLException: Column name not found.`

Is there a way to tell Hibernate to ignore the missing columns so that we can fetch only columns we need?

Edit: one of the answer suggested selecting `NULL` for each missing columns. The problem is that there might be probably around 40 columns and I certainly do not want to name them all.

Comment: What exactly is `em.selectNative("s.id, s.date", Sale.class)` ? It is not the JPA API, so kindly reformat using JPA API. People here don't know "your API"

Comment: you have a constructor of that class taking in just "id" and "date" ?

Comment: That was just a simplification, the default constructor is empty, Hibernate sets the fields not via constructor, but via reflection on fields. My point is that I want to create the entity without having to read the full row from the database.

Comment: there's no defined requirement in the JPA spec, so you have to rely on JPA provider specifics. The JPA provider I use (DataNucleus JPA) supports finding constructor with arguments in the results order, or using setters etc. Your JPA provider clearly doesn't do that, so you are better off reading their docs

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
em.createNamedQuery("SELECT id, date, cast(null as char(1)) name, cast(null as char(1)) kind from sale", Sale.class);
```

Please note that `char` may need to change based on the data types of `name` and `kind`.

Comment: Well this would work, the problem is that there is around 40 columns and I certainly don't want to name them all :/

Comment: Realistically, the overhead of pulling 40 columns even if you only plan to use 2 isn't that bad. That said, if you really want, you could always define a different entity for the table with only a few choice columns

Comment: I know it is not that bad, but it makes the query really long and when the entity changes, this query will have to be changed as well which might lead to human errors. I still don't like to write all of the columns. Also I don't want to define a new entity as i wouldn't be able to replace these two without using some interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some solution:

1. Use constructor expression:

   ```
   List<Sale> sales = em.createQuery(
       "SELECT new com.your.package.Sale(" + // Full package
       "       s.id, " +
       "       s.date " +
       "   ) " +
       "FROM Sale s ", Sale.class).getResultList();
   ```
2. Use ResultTransformer

   ```
   List<Sale> sales = em.createQuery(
       "SELECT s.id, s.date " +
       "FROM Sale s ", Sale.class)
     .unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class)
     .setResultTransformer(custom)
     .getResultList();
   ```

   Where the custom transformer is:

   ```
   ResultTransformer custom = new ResultTransformer() {
       @Override
       public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {
           Sale s = new Sale();
           // s.setTitle = tuple[0]
           // s.setDate = tuple[1]
           return s;
       }

       @Override
       public List transformList(List collection) {
           return collection;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use Hibernate Criteria API / Use JPA Criteria API

Comment: That's the ticket! Exactly the sort of thing I was hoping for. Enjoy the bounty! Hopefully this gets marked as the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Glad it helps

Answer (score 1):

Are the extra columns declared as `NULLable` and with `DEFAULT` values?

This might work:

```
em.createNamedQuery("SELECT id, date, NULL, NULL FROM sale", Sale.class);
```

where you place `NULL` in the right places for the various columns.  Or perhaps this is needed:

```
em.createNamedQuery("SELECT
        id, 
        date,
        NULL AS name,
        NULL AS kind
     FROM sale", Sale.class);
```

Comment: Do you know if this would work with spring data repositories, and with fields of child entities?

Comment: @JordanMackie - Sorry, I am totally ignorant of what levels of obfuscation Spring does or does not add.