# how to ignore entity values that are not being mapped by spring jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am running into the issue where I am making a query from one table and trying to map and store the results it returns into another table. There is one field in my new table that's unique to that table while the other values being mapped have the same name from the original mapped table. Now the problem I have is that hibernate is saying that a unique field is not part of the result set so it can't map it. What can I do to let hibernate know that this field is only part of the new table and not part of the table it' gets mapped from?

```
Table A
name
age


Table B
name 
age 
height


@Query(
        value = "select name, age, from table A group by (name, age)",
        nativeQuery = true
)
List<TableB> mapData();
```

Hiberate Returns
`The column name height was not found in this ResultSet.`

Comment: See if this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44409733/fetching-incomplete-object-with-hibernate-mapping-as-native-query

Answer (score 0):

I must remind you that such a return value can easily break the code design. For query operations on the same data table, the best option is to return the same pojo.

If you need to convert TableA to TableB in other logic, maybe you can search for "java object copy", for example: http://dozer.sourceforge.net/